# Google Calendar API Java 400 invalid_request

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

```
@Component
public class GoogleCalendarSyncListener implements ApplicationListener<CourseLessonGoogleCalendarNeedToBeUpdatedEvent> {

    private String getEventId(Lesson parameter) { // encapsulator method
        return "cita" + parameter.getId();
    }

    // TODO bu daha genel olabilir.
    @Configuration
    static class Configurator {
        @Bean
        public Calendar client() {
            List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
            try {
                Calendar client = CalendarUtils.createCalendarClient(scopes);
                return client;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private LessonService lessonService;
    @Autowired
    private LessonUserService lessonUserService;
    @Autowired
    private Calendar client; // bunu da confige taşımak lazım

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(CourseLessonGoogleCalendarNeedToBeUpdatedEvent courseLessonGoogleCalendarNeedToBeUpdatedEvent) {

        try {
            ProductType productType = courseLessonGoogleCalendarNeedToBeUpdatedEvent.getCourseRegistration().getCourse().getCategory().getProductType();
            Course course = courseLessonGoogleCalendarNeedToBeUpdatedEvent.getCourseRegistration().getCourse();
            List<Lesson> lessons = lessonService.loadLessonsByCourse(course);

            int lessonCount = lessons.size();

            for (Lesson lesson : lessons) {
                String description = "";
                try {
                    String eventId = getEventId(lesson);  // RFC2938 bu kurala uygun olmalı
                    DateTime start = new DateTime(lesson.getDate(), TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+03:00"));
                    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.setTime(lesson.getDate());
                    cal.add(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, lesson.getLessonPricingTemplate().getDurationMinutes());
                    cal.getTime();
                    DateTime end = new DateTime(cal.getTime(), TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+03:00"));

                    description  += lesson.getCourse().getCatName();

                    String color = "";

                    for (LessonUser lessonuser : lessonUserService.loadByLesson(lesson)) {
                        description +=  " " + lessonuser.getUser().getPrettyName();
                        switch (lessonuser.getUser().getUsername()) {
                            case "bgor":
                                color = Constants.BGORCOLOR;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    // TODO error checdking

                    description += lessonService.lessonIndex(lesson) + "/" + lessonCount;

                    Event event = new Event();
                    event.setColorId(color);
                    event.setId(eventId);
                    event.setReminders(new Event.Reminders().setUseDefault(false));
                    event.setSummary(description);
                    event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
                    event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));
                    event.setDescription(lesson.getCourse().getCatName());

                    List<EventAttendee> attendees = new ArrayList<>();
                    EventAttendee admin = new EventAttendee();
                    admin.setEmail("mail@btmuzik.com");
                    attendees.add(admin);

                    List<LessonUser> lessonUsers = lessonUserService.loadByLesson(lesson);
                    lessonUsers.forEach(lu -> {
                        EventAttendee attendee = new EventAttendee();
                        if (lu.getUser().getEmail() != null) {
                            attendee.setEmail(lu.getUser().getEmail());
                            attendees.add(attendee);
                        }
                    });

                    event.setAttendees(attendees);

                    Event.Creator creator = new Event.Creator();
                    Event.Organizer organizer = new Event.Organizer();
                    creator.setEmail("mail@btmuzik.com");
                    organizer.setEmail("mail@btmuzik.com");
                    event.setCreator(creator);
                    event.setOrganizer(organizer);

                    logger.info("event %s (%s)\n", event.getSummary(), start);

                    saveOrUpdateEvent(event);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    // By existing conf tomcat/.store/bt-calendar-sync/StoredCredentials must exist
    // These are copy of  btmuzikevi-parent/tokens/StoredCredential  created by CalendarReader

    private Event saveOrUpdateEvent(Event event) {
        try {
            System.out.println("client = " + client.getBaseUrl());
            System.out.println("client = " + client.getRootUrl());
            System.out.println("event.getId() = " + event.getId());

            List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
            client = CalendarUtils.createCalendarClient(scopes);
            Calendar.Events.List request = client.events().list("primary");

            System.out.println("--------------------------------- ");

            event = client.events().update("primary", event.getId(), event).execute(); // updated event
            System.out.println(event.getId()+ " HUHA = " + event.getStart());
            return event;
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) { // burası özel bir değer veriyor
            try {
                event = client.events().insert("primary", event).execute();
                return event;
            } catch (IOException ioException) { // bu çok özel değil ama tüm detayı içeriyor
                throw new RuntimeException(ioException); // tamamını runtimeexception olarak dönüyoruz.
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

## Requested Oauth2 scopes:

- Google Calendar API   .../auth/calendar   See, edit, share, and  permanently delete all the calendars you can access using Google Calendar
- Google Calendar API   .../auth/calendar.acls  See and change the sharing permissions of Google calendars you own
- Google Calendar API   .../auth/calendar.events    View and edit events on all your calendars

CalendarQuickstart  or CalendarReader are fine, they read from the calendar but:
When I try to write into the Calendar, I am getting :

> Authorization Error
> Error 400: invalid_request
> Required parameter is missing: response_type

What am I missing?
Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Have you tried the solutions suggested in these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835222/google-api-oauth-2-0-titanium-required-parameter-is-missing-response-type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842176/google-oauth2-response-type-error-on-authorization-code-request

Comment: You need to recuce your code to find which parameter is giving you the error. Start with the basic required parameters (start and end) and gradually add more. Once you know which parameter is the culpit, it will be easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

There is something major wrong with how you are authncateing the library if you are getting that message.   The best tutorial i know of for Java with the google api java client library is the one for [google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-java)

I have tried to translate it for you to calendar it should be close.

```
/**
 * A simple example of how to access the Google Calendar API.
 */
public class HelloCalendar {
  // Path to client_secrets.json file downloaded from the Developer's Console.
  // The path is relative to HelloAnalytics.java.
  private static final String CLIENT_SECRET_JSON_RESOURCE = "client_secrets.json";

  // Replace with your view ID.
  private static final String VIEW_ID = "<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>";

  // The directory where the user's credentials will be stored.
  private static final File DATA_STORE_DIR = new File(
      System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/hello_calendar");

  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Hello Calendar";
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
  private static NetHttpTransport httpTransport;
  private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Calendar service = initializeCalendarReporting();

      // make call here
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  /**
   * Initializes an authorized Calendar service object.
   *
   * @return The Calendar service object.
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws GeneralSecurityException
   */
  private static Calendar initializeCalendar() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);

    // Load client secrets.
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
        new InputStreamReader(HelloCalendar.class
            .getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRET_JSON_RESOURCE)));

    // Set up authorization code flow for all authorization scopes.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
        .Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
            CalendarScopes.all()).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
        .build();

    // Authorize.
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow,
        new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    // Construct the Calendar service object.
    return new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
  }
```

Comment: The peculiar part is that the code I submitted works perfectly OK for some other account and oauth consent which is the exact replica of this. Therefore I'm little puzzled. I will check what you submitted tomorrow :)

Comment: Are you sure you created the corect type of client credentials because that error should not be happening if you have the proper oauth2 code.

Comment: @DalmTo : Thanks for the comment. You are right, I suspect it is not java code related but purely oauth2 caused. I have dig in there what I am missing :)